I'm unable to match the java version with gradle within flutter
I keep getting the error "Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for Gradle." no matter which versions of the JDK I select, kotlin version, AGP version or gradle version I specify.
Flutter error
I'm still a beginner in using flutter and Android Studio. I've tried using the AGP upgrade assistant and can get it to build successfully within the sync when picking the latest version available i.e. gradle 8.9. But when I type flutter run within terminal, I still get the below error message.
My application worked a while ago before upgrading to dart 3.0, but since trying to rollback, I've not been able to get it working again.
Is there something fairly obvious I'm missing?
Plugin versions
Settings

Which version are you using for flutter ? can you share flutter doctor -v

Not sure how to share an image of my flutter doctor -v run. But I think I've somehow managed to "fix" this error by uninstalling the latest android studio and redownloading android studio dolphin. I made sure to downgrade dart to 2.19.6, flutter to 3.7.12, JDK 11, gradle plugin 7.2.0, kotlin 1.8.0, gradle distribution 7.5. Is it normal for later versions of dart and flutter to break an application?

using latest version will provide you better functionality. downgrading will work but you may miss new features or fixes which were done in latest one.  Android studio ladybug is the latest one. you are also using android studio older

I was using ladybug but kept getting the error about "Your project's gradle is incompatible with the Java version...", no matter which JDK or gradle version I used. Is there an easy way to find a set of versions that all play together nicely for ladybug?

The "fix" for me was to uninstall android studio and downgrade from the latest version, all the way back to Dolphin. Firebase doesn't quite work how it should but the app seems to be working. These are the versions of things I'm using now in case it helps anyone else having the same problem as me.
gradle plugin 7.2.2
gradle distribution 7.5
kotlin 1.8.0
java 17
dart 2.17.1
flutter 3.0.1
